# Large Scale Edit

Tags: support, editing

Many times when I edit someone else's post the changes take effect immediately. I don't know if they accept them that quickly or its because of my rep. I would like to propose large scale edit to someone's post but I don't want it to take effect without their or community approval.

How should I got about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you got 2000 rep points, your edit is applied immediately and does not go to the Suggested Edit queue. This is a privilege acquired after reaching that milestone.

A large scale edit with only formatting rework is fine, however be careful with changing the question completely. It might invalidates existing answers, and it's a big no-no.

Edit can always be rolled back, so usually if you make an edit in a good faith (after considering existing answers and the author intent), it is fine.

Comment: That's the thing I want to help them revise their scope, hence why I want their approval.

Comment: @anon then just post in comments and wait for their approval. Generally, even the author should avoid edit that invalidates answers. If you edit with a good faith, and after careful consideration of the existing answers and author intent, go ahead. If the author doesn't like it, he can always roll it back.

Comment: @anon What Vylix said. Also, if you make a substantial edit to a post, it's often considered good tone to leave a comment to the effect of "I've edited your post for Reason X and Y, if you disagree feel free to edit further or roll back the edit". I usually try to put the emphasis in such cases on editing further, while pointing out that rolling back the edit entirely is an option.